# The exponential operator in Matlab grammar using ANTLR4 does not work correctly

Tags: matlab, antlr4, grammar, operator-keyword, exponential

I have been using matlab grammar from [this](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/matlab) source. I came across an error to the following input

```
a = 2^2*3
b = 3*2^2
```

Result in both cases should be 12, but it is not, because the exponential operator in Matlab grammar using ANTLR4 does not work correctly which shows following tree [image]

Problem might be in the multiplicative expression, but I do not have best solution for the issue in my mind. To be honest I do not have any solution for this. Can anybody please tell me how to fix this?

```
multiplicative_expression
   : unary_expression
   | multiplicative_expression '*' unary_expression
   | multiplicative_expression '/' unary_expression
   | multiplicative_expression '\\' unary_expression
   | multiplicative_expression '^' unary_expression
   | multiplicative_expression ARRAYMUL unary_expression
   | multiplicative_expression ARRAYDIV unary_expression
   | multiplicative_expression ARRAYRDIV unary_expression
   | multiplicative_expression ARRAYPOW unary_expression
   ;
```

Comment: This grammar gives exponentiation the same level of precedence as multiplication by putting it inside of the same non-terminal. In order to give it a higher level of precedence, you'll either need to introduce another non-terminal / level of precedence that goes between `multiplicative_expression` and `unary_expression` or, if possible for this grammar, get rid of the different expression non-terminal altogether and define a single left-recursive `expression` rule that uses ANTLR's built-in precedence support by defining operators in the order of their precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace the section `multiplicative_expression` with the following:

```
multiplicative_expression
   : pow_expression
   | multiplicative_expression '*' pow_expression
   | multiplicative_expression '/' pow_expression
   | multiplicative_expression '\\' pow_expression
   | multiplicative_expression ARRAYMUL pow_expression
   | multiplicative_expression ARRAYDIV pow_expression
   | multiplicative_expression ARRAYRDIV pow_expression
   ;
```

and then include an additional section `pow_expression`:

```
pow_expression
   : unary_expression
   | pow_expression '^' unary_expression
   | pow_expression ARRAYPOW unary_expression
   ;
```

That should give the exponentiation operators a higher precedence than the multiplicative operators.

However, if you're trying to actually implement MATLAB's actual grammar, you should realize that this grammar on GitHub is not a very good reflection of it. MATLAB has further exponentiation operators (`.^-`, `.^+`, `.^~`, `^-`, `^+`, `^~`) for example, and there are entire categories of syntax, e.g. all the object-oriented functionality, that are not covered at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answear. It seems to work. Anyway this grammar fits for my use now, but if you know where I can get better representation of Matlab grammar, so I will be more than pleased if you share it.

Comment: MATLAB’s grammar is quite complicated and if you try to implement it yourself you’ll find a lot of problematic edge cases. For example, it’s whitespace-sensitive, in that `[2+3]` is a different expression to `[2 +3]`. It’s proprietary, and I’m not aware of a correct, publicly available version.